# Rollback migration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration, rollback

I want to write down() function in migration and after run rollback command I'm getting error.

Migration that i want to rollback looks like this:

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('competition_id')->after('content_id')->nullable()->constrained('competitions');
            $table->unique(['account_id', 'competition_id']);
        });
    }
```

Rollback function looks like this:

```
public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('competition_id');
        });
    }
```

When I run php artisan migrate:rollback I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'competition_id' doesn't exist in table (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `posts` drop `competition_id`)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. I must rollback in the following order.

Drop both foreign keys that are part of composite unique constraint:

```
$table->dropForeign(['competition_id']);
$table->dropForeign(['account_id']);
```

Drop composite unique constraint:

```
$table->dropUnique(['account_id', 'competition_id']);
```

Drop column:

```
$table->dropColumn('competition_id');
```

Finally recreate account_id foreign key:

```
$table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts');
```

So the final migration looks like this:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('competition_id')->after('content_id')->nullable()->constrained('competitions');
        $table->unique(['account_id', 'competition_id']);
    });
}

public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['competition_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['account_id']);
        $table->dropUnique(['account_id', 'competition_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('competition_id');
        $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts');
    });
}
```